# Parse string as list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

Input: `'(tagname1, tagvalue1),(tagname2,tagvalue2), ( tagname3, tagvalue3 ), (tag name4,tag value4)'`

Output: `[("tagname1", "tagvalue1"), ("tagname2", "tagvalue2"), ("tagname3", "tagvalue3"), ("tag name4", "tag value4")]`

I have a solution but it's working only if the input contains quotes for each element: `"tagname1", "tagvalue1" ...`

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(input_string)
```

In my case I receive: `ValueError: malformed string`

Any solution to have it working (please see the spaces, too)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try another approach, with regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '(tagname1, tagvalue1),(tagname2,tagvalue2), ( tagname3, tagvalue3 ), (tag name4,tag value4)'
>>> e = '\(\s?(.*?)\s?,\s?(.*?)\s?\)'
>>> re.findall(e, s)
[('tagname1', 'tagvalue1'), ('tagname2', 'tagvalue2'), ('tagname3', 'tagvalue3'), ('tag name4', 'tag value4')]
```

Comment: Bleh nevermind, my solution is obviously wrong. This is perfect!

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: It still doesn't handle multiple spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach to what Burhan suggested is utilizing power of back references. You can read more about back-references [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

```
import re

# Input string
string = '(tagname1, tagvalue1),(tagname2,tagvalue2), ( tagname3, tagvalue3 ), (tag name4,tag value4)'

# Regular expression pattern 
pattern = re.compile(r"\(([a-z0-9 ]+), ?([a-z0-9 ]+)\)", re.I)

list_of_tupples = []
for matched_object in pattern.finditer(string):
    list_of_tupples.append((matched_object.group(1), matched_object.group(2)))
```

You can see regular expression demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/NYjhi4/1).

**Note:**

I also used use `pattern.finditter()` because that way you can iterate trough all pattern findings in text. From *re.finditer* documentation:

> re.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0) Return an iterator yielding
>   MatchObject instances over all non-overlapping matches for the RE
>   pattern in string. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches
>   are returned in the order found. Empty matches are included in the
>   result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `re.findall` variant that does handle multiple spaces (non-word characters):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '(tagname1, tagvalue1  ),  ( tagname2 ,   tagvalue2   ), (      tagname3, tagvalue3 ), (tag name4,   tag value4   )'
>>> re.findall('\(\W*([\w\s]*?)\W*,\W*([\w\s]*?)\W*\)', s)
[('tagname1', 'tagvalue1'), ('tagname2', 'tagvalue2'), ('tagname3', 'tagvalue3'), ('tag name4', 'tag value4')]
```

Notice the non-greedy closure (repetition qualifier) after word characters (including spaces), `[\w\s]*?`. This ensures **all words** for each tag name/value are captured, but **excluding all leading and trailing spaces**. That's why `"tag value4"` is properly captured above.

Comment: tag name4, tag value4 - missing in the output

Comment: I've missed that case (spaces in middle). Fixed it. Now it'll **strip leading and trailing spaces**, but **preserve spaces in the middle**.

Comment: Great. Regex is witchcraft for me. :D

Answer (score 1):

Another, non-regex method:

```
def string_to_tuples(s):
    def tuple_strip(s):  # Wrapper to pass to map
        return s.strip(" ()")

    sl = map(tuple_strip, s.split(","))
    return zip(sl[::2], sl[1::2])
```

Which yields:

```
>>> string_to_tuples('(tagname1, tagvalue1),(tagname2,tagvalue2), ( tagname3, tagvalue3 ), (tag name4,tag value4)')
[('tagname1', 'tagvalue1'), ('tagname2', 'tagvalue2'), ('tagname3', 'tagvalue3'), ('tag name4', 'tag value4')]
```

and will work as long as tags cannot start or end with (space), `(`, or `)` and don't include any `,`s.